# React / Nextjs: .map() output based on state array doesn't rerender because of keys don't change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a react component `Matches.js` that handles the output of tournament matches, sorted by their rounds. All the data is fetched from a parent component which fetches it via nextjs SSR and then gives the data as props to the child component. To avoid additional requests via page reloads based on data changes (new, update, delete), I'm trying to update the output via a state array `matches`, which is updated by child components if the backend request worked. It works flawlessly with add and delete operations, but updating gives me serious headaches. Only updating a match item doesn't rerender the match output at all.

For displaying the matches, I use the const `displayMatches` which maps matches according to their rounds, so two .map() functions. I've pinpointed the problem to the keys which react demands as unique props. When they don't change, `displayMatches` doesn't rerender with the updated data. I'm using `match._id` as unique values for the keys which always stay the same. I tried randomizing the the id a bit, but the results were weird and wonky at best.

How may I trigger a rerender with the updated values after an update operations? I'd like to avoid going the 'easy way' by just forcing the page to reload, which works fine.

The data of the state array is clearly updated on time, as seen in console.logs. The array consists of objects like this one:

```
{
        tournamentId: tournamentId,
        _id: id,
        encho: encho,
        round: round,
        red: {
            name: redName,
            ippon: redIppon,
            hansoku: redHansoku,
            winByHantei: redWinByHantei
        },
        white: {
            name: whiteName,
            ippon: whiteIppon,
            hansoku: whiteHansoku,
            winByHantei: whiteWinByHantei
        }
```

`Matches.js`:

```
import { useState } from "react"

import SingleMatchView from "./SingleMatchView"
import SingleMatchEdit from "./SingleMatchEdit"

import { roundMap, refreshPage } from "../../store/helpers"

import Button from "@mui/material/Button"
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack"
import RefreshIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Refresh"

export default function Matches({
    matches: matchData,
    isLoggedIn,
    tournamentId
}) {
    const [matches, setMatches] = useState(matchData)

    const [sortASC, setSortASC] = useState(true)

    const addMatchToState = (match) => {
        return setMatches((prev) => [...prev, match])
    }

    const updateMatchInState = (updateData) => {
        setMatches((prev) => {
            return prev.map((match) => {
                if (updateData._id === match._id) {
                    return {
                        ...match,
                        ...updateData
                    }
                }
                return match
            })
        })
    }

    const deleteMatchInState = (matchId) => {
        return setMatches((prev) => {
            return prev.filter((match) => {
                return match._id != matchId
            })
        })
    }

    const uniqueRounds = [...new Set(matches?.map((match) => match.round))]

    const displayMatches = uniqueRounds.map((round) => {
        return (
            <div key={round}>
                <h2>{roundMap[round]}</h2>
                {matches
                    .filter((match) => match.round === round)
                    .map((match) => (
                        <SingleMatchView
                            key={match._id}
                            tournamentId={tournamentId}
                            matchData={match}
                            isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
                            deleteMatchInState={deleteMatchInState}
                            updateMatchInState={updateMatchInState}
                        />
                    ))}
            </div>
        )
    })

    console.log("Matches rerendered")
    return (
        <>
            <Stack direction="row" spacing={2} my={2} justifyContent={"center"}>
                <Button
                    onClick={() => setSortASC((prev) => !prev)}
                    variant="contained"
                    color="secondary"
                >
                    {sortASC ? "Sort Pool ➝ Final" : "Sort Final ➝ Pool"}
                </Button>
                <Button
                    onClick={refreshPage}
                    variant="contained"
                    startIcon={<RefreshIcon />}
                    color="secondary"
                >
                    Refresh
                </Button>
            </Stack>

            {isLoggedIn && (
                <SingleMatchEdit
                    addMatchToState={addMatchToState}
                    isNew={true}
                    tournamentId={tournamentId}
                />
            )}

            {matches.length === 0 && "No matches yet"}

            {sortASC ? displayMatches : displayMatches.reverse()}
        </>
    )
}
```

/edit: additional code

`SingleMatchView.js`

```
import { useState } from "react"

import { roundMap } from "../../store/helpers"
import SingleMatchEdit from "./SingleMatchEdit"
import { httpDeleteIndividualMatch } from "../../hooks/requests"

import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack"
import Button from "@mui/material/Button"
import DeleteIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Delete"
import EditIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Edit"
import ClearIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Clear"

export default function SingleMatchView({
    tournamentId,
    matchData,
    isLoggedIn,
    updateMatchInState,
    deleteMatchInState
}) {
    const hansokuIcon = "▲"

    const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false)

    const [confirmDelete, setConfirmDelete] = useState(false)

    const [encho, setEncho] = useState(matchData?.encho || false)
    const [round, setRound] = useState(
        matchData?.round || Object.keys(roundMap)[0]
    )

    const [redName, setRedName] = useState(matchData?.red?.name || "")
    const [redIppon, setRedIppon] = useState(matchData?.red?.ippon || "")
    const [redHansoku, setRedHansoku] = useState(matchData?.red?.hansoku || 0)
    const [redWinByHantei, setRedWinByHantei] = useState(
        matchData?.red?.winByHantei || false
    )

    const [whiteName, setWhiteName] = useState(matchData?.white?.name || "")
    const [whiteIppon, setWhiteIppon] = useState(matchData?.white?.ippon || "")
    const [whiteHansoku, setWhiteHansoku] = useState(
        matchData?.white?.hansoku || 0
    )
    const [whiteWinByHantei, setWhiteWinByHantei] = useState(
        matchData?.white?.winByHantei || false
    )

    const redPoints = redIppon.length + Math.floor(whiteHansoku / 2)
    const whitePoints = whiteIppon.length + Math.floor(redHansoku / 2)
    const redIpponIcons = redIppon?.split("").map((ippon, i) => {
        return (
            <span key={i} className="ippon-icon">
                {ippon}
            </span>
        )
    })
    const whiteIpponIcons = whiteIppon?.split("").map((ippon, i) => {
        return (
            <span key={i} className="ippon-icon">
                {ippon}
            </span>
        )
    })

    const isHikiWake = redPoints === whitePoints

    // const dataObject = {
    //     encho: encho,
    //     round: round,
    //     red: {
    //         name: redName.trim(),
    //         ippon: redIppon,
    //         hansoku: redHansoku,
    //         winByHantei: redWinByHantei
    //     },
    //     white: {
    //         name: whiteName.trim(),
    //         ippon: whiteIppon,
    //         hansoku: whiteHansoku,
    //         winByHantei: whiteWinByHantei
    //     }
    // }

    let deleteTimer

    const prepareDeleteFight = async () => {
        setConfirmDelete(true)
        deleteTimer = setTimeout(() => {
            setConfirmDelete(false)
        }, 5000)
    }

    const confirmDeleteFight = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await httpDeleteIndividualMatch(matchData._id)
            if (response.acknowledged) {
                return deleteMatchInState(matchData._id)
            }
            console.log("Error, match not deleted")
            return
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } finally {
            setConfirmDelete(false)
            clearTimeout(deleteTimer)
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="display">
                {/* {matchData._id} */}
                {/* {round && <div className="round">{round}</div>} */}
                <div className="board-single-results">
                    <div className="red-color stripe"></div>

                    <div
                        className="red-name"
                        // Warning: Prop `style` did not match. Server: "null" Client: "background-color:"
                        // style={{
                        //     "background-color":
                        //         redPoints > whitePoints ? "gold" : ""
                        // }}
                    >
                        {redName.toUpperCase() || "???"}
                    </div>
                    <div className="hansoku red-hansoku">
                        {hansokuIcon.repeat(redHansoku)}
                    </div>

                    <div className="ippon red-ippon">
                        {redIppon && redIpponIcons.reverse()}
                    </div>

                    <div className="points red-points">{redPoints}</div>

                    <div className="win-modifier">
                        {
                            // to do: Encho geht nicht gleichzeitig mit Hikiwake, check einfügen
                        }
                        {encho && !isHikiWake && "E"}
                        {!encho && isHikiWake && <ClearIcon />}
                    </div>

                    <div className="points white-points">{whitePoints}</div>

                    <div className="ippon white-ippon">
                        {whiteIppon && whiteIpponIcons}
                    </div>

                    <div className="hansoku white-hansoku">
                        {hansokuIcon.repeat(whiteHansoku)}
                    </div>

                    <div
                        className="white-name"
                        // Warning: Prop `style` did not match. Server: "null" Client: "background-color:"
                        // style={{
                        //     "background-color":
                        //         whitePoints > redPoints ? "gold" : ""
                        // }}
                    >
                        {whiteName.toUpperCase()}
                    </div>

                    <div className="white-color stripe"></div>
                </div>

                {isLoggedIn && (
                    <div className="toolbox">
                        <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
                            <Button
                                onClick={() => setEditMode((prev) => !prev)}
                                variant="contained"
                                startIcon={<EditIcon />}
                                size="small"
                            >
                                EDIT
                            </Button>

                            {!confirmDelete && (
                                <Button
                                    onClick={prepareDeleteFight}
                                    color="error"
                                    variant="contained"
                                    startIcon={<DeleteIcon />}
                                    size="small"
                                >
                                    Delete
                                </Button>
                            )}
                            {confirmDelete && (
                                <Button
                                    onClick={confirmDeleteFight}
                                    color="error"
                                    variant="contained"
                                    startIcon={<DeleteIcon />}
                                    size="small"
                                >
                                    Confirm Deletion
                                </Button>
                            )}
                        </Stack>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>

            {editMode && (
                <SingleMatchEdit
                    matchData={matchData}
                    tournamentId={tournamentId}
                    setEditMode={setEditMode}
                    updateMatchInState={updateMatchInState}
                />
            )}
        </>
    )
}
```

`SingleMatchEdit.js` (`handleSubmitUpdate` being the important part here)

```
export default function SingleMatchEdit({
    matchData,
    isNew,
    tournamentId,
    setEditMode,
    updateMatchInState,
    addMatchToState
}) {
    const matchId = matchData?._id
    const [encho, setEncho] = useState(matchData?.encho || false)
    const [round, setRound] = useState(
        matchData?.round || Object.keys(roundMap)[0]
    )
    const [redName, setRedName] = useState(matchData?.red?.name || "")
    const [redIppon, setRedIppon] = useState(matchData?.red?.ippon || "")
    const [redHansoku, setRedHansoku] = useState(matchData?.red?.hansoku || 0)
    const [redWinByHantei, setRedWinByHantei] = useState(
        matchData?.red?.winByHantei || false
    )
    const [whiteName, setWhiteName] = useState(matchData?.white?.name || "")
    const [whiteIppon, setWhiteIppon] = useState(matchData?.white?.ippon || "")
    const [whiteHansoku, setWhiteHansoku] = useState(
        matchData?.white?.hansoku || 0
    )
    const [whiteWinByHantei, setWhiteWinByHantei] = useState(
        matchData?.white?.winByHantei || false
    )

    const resetMatchData = () => {
        setEncho(false)
        setRound(Object.keys(roundMap)[0])
        setRedName("")
        setRedIppon("")
        setRedHansoku(0)
        setRedWinByHantei(false)
        setWhiteName("")
        setWhiteIppon("")
        setWhiteHansoku(0)
        setWhiteWinByHantei(false)
    }

    const addRedIppon = (e) => {
        if (redIppon.length >= 2) return
        setRedIppon((prev) => prev.concat(e.target.name))
    }
    const remRedIppon = () => setRedIppon("")

    const addWhiteIppon = (e) => {
        if (whiteIppon.length >= 2) return
        setWhiteIppon((prev) => prev.concat(e.target.name))
    }
    const remWhiteIppon = () => setWhiteIppon("")

    const redIpponButtons = ipponButtons(ipponMap, addRedIppon, "red")
    const whiteIpponButtons = ipponButtons(ipponMap, addWhiteIppon, "white")

    const matchDataToSend = {
        tournamentId: tournamentId,
        encho: encho,
        round: round,
        red: {
            name: redName.trim(),
            ippon: redIppon,
            hansoku: redHansoku,
            winByHantei: redWinByHantei
        },
        white: {
            name: whiteName.trim(),
            ippon: whiteIppon,
            hansoku: whiteHansoku,
            winByHantei: whiteWinByHantei
        }
    }

    const handleSubmitNew = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        try {
            const response = await httpSubmitMatch(matchDataToSend)
            if (response.acknowledged) {
                addMatchToState({
                    ...matchDataToSend,
                    _id: response.insertedId
                })
                resetMatchData()
            }
            if (!response.acknowledged) {
                // do something
                throw new Error("Data not acklowleged!")
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }

    const handleSubmitUpdate = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        try {
            const response = await httpUpdateIndividualMatch(
                matchId,
                matchDataToSend
            )
            if (response.acknowledged) {
                // To Do: Update State
                updateMatchInState({ ...matchDataToSend, _id: matchId })
                setEditMode(false)
            }
            if (!response.acknowledged) {
                // do something
                throw new Error("Data not acklowleged!")
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }

    function removeRedHansoku() {
        if (redHansoku <= 0) return
        setRedHansoku((prev) => prev - 1)
    }

    function addRedHansoku() {
        if (redHansoku >= 4) return
        setRedHansoku((prev) => prev + 1)
    }

    function removeWhiteHansoku() {
        if (whiteHansoku <= 0) return
        setWhiteHansoku((prev) => prev - 1)
    }

    function addWhiteHansoku() {
        if (whiteHansoku >= 4) return
        setWhiteHansoku((prev) => prev + 1)
    }

    const rounds = Object.keys(roundMap).map((round) => {
        return (
            // <option key={round} value={round}>
            //     {roundMap[round]}
            // </option>
            <MenuItem key={round} value={round}>
                {roundMap[round]}
            </MenuItem>
        )
    })

    return (
        <div className={styles["edit-board"]}>
            <div className={styles["board"]}>
                <div className={styles["red-color"]}></div>
                <div className={styles["red-name"]}>
                    {/* Replace with Autocomplete and a list of all names that were entered in the past, retrieved from DB */}
                    {/* <TextField
            fullWidth
            id="outlined-basic"
            label="Name"
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
            margin="normal"
            value={redName}
            onChange={(e) => setRedName(e.target.value)}
          /> */}
                    <AutocompletePlayerName
                        value={redName}
                        setNameFunc={setRedName}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className={styles["white-name"]}>
                    {/* Replace with Autocomplete and a list of all names that were entered in the past, retrieved from DB */}
                    {/* <TextField
            fullWidth
            id="outlined-basic"
            label="Name"
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
            margin="normal"
            value={whiteName}
            onChange={(e) => setWhiteName(e.target.value)}
          /> */}
                    <AutocompletePlayerName
                        value={whiteName}
                        setNameFunc={setWhiteName}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className={styles["white-color"]}></div>

                <div className={`${styles.ippon} ${styles["red-ippon"]}`}>
                    <div className={styles["awarded-ippon"]}>
                        {redIppon ? `➝${redIppon}` : "(IPPON)"}
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles["add-ippon-icon-table"]}>
                        {redIpponButtons}
                    </div>
                    <Button
                        color="warning"
                        variant="contained"
                        startIcon={<CancelOutlinedIcon />}
                        size="small"
                        onClick={remRedIppon}
                    >
                        Reset Ippon
                    </Button>
                </div>

                <div className={`${styles.ippon} ${styles["white-ippon"]}`}>
                    <div className={styles["awarded-ippon"]}>
                        {whiteIppon ? `➝${whiteIppon}` : "(IPPON)"}
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles["add-ippon-icon-table"]}>
                        {whiteIpponButtons}
                    </div>
                    <Button
                        color="warning"
                        variant="contained"
                        startIcon={<CancelOutlinedIcon />}
                        size="small"
                        onClick={remWhiteIppon}
                    >
                        Reset Ippon
                    </Button>
                </div>

                <div
                    className={styles["red-hansoku"]}
                    style={{ justifyContent: "space-between" }}
                >
                    <IconButton
                        onClick={removeRedHansoku}
                        sx={{ color: "#00000078" }}
                    >
                        <RemoveCircleIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                    {redHansoku ? "▲".repeat(redHansoku) : "(HANSOKU)"}
                    <IconButton
                        onClick={addRedHansoku}
                        sx={{ color: "#00000078" }}
                    >
                        <AddCircleIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                </div>

                <div
                    className={styles["white-hansoku"]}
                    style={{ justifyContent: "space-between" }}
                >
                    <IconButton
                        onClick={removeWhiteHansoku}
                        sx={{ color: "#00000078" }}
                    >
                        <RemoveCircleIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                    {whiteHansoku ? "▲".repeat(whiteHansoku) : "(HANSOKU)"}
                    <IconButton
                        onClick={addWhiteHansoku}
                        sx={{ color: "#00000078" }}
                    >
                        <AddCircleIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                </div>

                <div className={styles["additional-information"]}>
                    <FormControl variant="standard" size="small">
                        <Select
                            labelId=""
                            id=""
                            value={round}
                            label="Round"
                            onChange={(e) => setRound(e.target.value)}
                        >
                            {rounds}
                        </Select>

                        {/* <select
                            name="round"
                            value={round}
                            onChange={(e) => setRound(e.target.value)}
                        >
                            {rounds}
                        </select> */}

                        <FormControlLabel
                            control={
                                <Checkbox
                                    checked={encho}
                                    onChange={() => setEncho((prev) => !prev)}
                                />
                            }
                            label="Encho"
                        />
                    </FormControl>

                    {/* <label>
                        <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            defaultChecked={encho}
                            onChange={() => setEncho((prev) => !prev)}
                        />{" "}
                        Encho
                    </label> */}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className={styles.toolbox}>
                {!isNew && (
                    <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
                        <Button
                            onClick={() => setEditMode((prev) => !prev)}
                            variant="contained"
                            startIcon={<EditIcon />}
                            size="small"
                        >
                            CANCEL
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                            onClick={handleSubmitUpdate}
                            variant="contained"
                            startIcon={<EditIcon />}
                            size="small"
                        >
                            Submit UPDATE
                        </Button>
                    </Stack>
                )}

                {isNew && (
                    <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
                        <Button
                            color="warning"
                            variant="contained"
                            startIcon={<CancelOutlinedIcon />}
                            size="small"
                            onClick={resetMatchData}
                        >
                            Reset
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                            onClick={handleSubmitNew}
                            variant="contained"
                            startIcon={<SendIcon />}
                            size="small"
                        >
                            Submit NEW
                        </Button>
                    </Stack>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

/edit 2: Solution
Based on Milos Pavlovic comment (marked solution), I've updated `SingleMatchView.js`. I put the `matchData` into it's own state and included a `useEffect` to listen to changes in `matchData`. Thanks!

Updated `SingleMatchView.js`:

```
    // ...imports
        export default function SingleMatchView({
            tournamentId,
            matchData,
            isLoggedIn,
            updateMatchInState,
            deleteMatchInState
        }) {
            const hansokuIcon = "▲"
        
            const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false)
            const [confirmDelete, setConfirmDelete] = useState(false)
        
            // deleted all individual state
            
//    edit: even simpler, no state needed
            // deleted: const [match, setMatch] = useState(matchData)
// added: 
const match = matchData
        
            useEffect(() => {
                setMatch(matchData)
            }, [matchData])
        
            const redPoints =
                match.red.ippon.length + Math.floor(match.white.hansoku / 2)
            const whitePoints =
                match.white.ippon.length + Math.floor(match.red.hansoku / 2)
    ...character limit
```

Comment: The `id`s aren't likely to be the problem. Please reduce the code in the question to a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). We'll probably be able to help you.

Comment: Part with the keys looks fine, it should not be the cause of your problem. Please share code for `SingleMatchView`, since that is the one not rerendering properly when some of its props change.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm struggling with stack snippets, it may take a while.

Comment: @Jakyo - No worries, just ping me when you're ready, I'll be happy to take a look and help out if I can. :-)

Comment: @MilosPavlovic I included `SingleMatchView` and `SingleMatchEdit`. Each value in `SingleMatchView` is handled by state.

Comment: Does `httpUpdateIndividualMatch` works fine, you managed to update match properly?

Comment: @MilosPavlovic Yes, the request to update to the DB works fine, it updates properly. The state is also updated properly, I've checked the state array in `Matches.js` and the matchData in `SingleMatchView.js`. It always shows the updated values in the console, but it doesn't rerender with these updated values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at your code I would say that your problem lies inside `SingleMatchView`. As I can see you have multiple useStates that use `matchData` in order to fill state initial values. What is wrong here is the fact that you are not "resetting" those state values once you successfully update certain match.
`SingleMatchView` element will just rerender, and not to recreate, after update finish its work, meaning that you must find a way to reset(to new values) all those states that are using `matchData` prop for their values, otherwise you will end up with unchanged values across whole element lifecycle.

Let's explain problem using this line inside `SingleMatchView`:

```
    const [redName, setRedName] = useState(matchData?.red?.name || "")
```

As we can see `redName` is initialized only once. Now imagine that inside `SingleMatchEdit` you are updating `redName`. What current code does is that inside `handleSubmitUpdate` you just call state updater from root component and that is all, problem is that `SingleMatchView` is not aware of update because this element uses its inner state, which is declared and assigned only once, and with that approach you decoupled from root component state and not listening to state updates at all - and that is why you will never rerender with updated info, because you never recompute your inner state inside `SingleMatchView` based on new prop value for `matchData`.

One solution would be to put useEffect inside `SingleMatchView` to listen for `matchData` change, and whenever prop value changes you should (re)set all states to new, latest, values, thus forcing content to rerender. Other solution is to intercept handler execution inside `SingleMatchView`, and before/after calling `updateMatchInState` you just (re)set state.

Comment: I feel pretty stupid now. All in all, it seems the problem was with decoupling the state from `Matches` and `SingleMatchView` by creating a new state in `SingleMatchView`. I completely removed the state in `SingleMatchView` now (just using the received props) and it still works. Original goal achieved, being the state in `Matches` to be the state to rule them all. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, that sounds even better, no redundant useStates anymore! :)